# Using MEF and XAML together

Tags: .net, xaml, mef

MEF is a great framework. I can just put a dll into given directory and when host composition goes the DLL code will run.

The question is if it is possible to create objects and use interfaces from XAML description, not from DLLs, in the case?

Comment: I am not quite clear on what you are asking for. Can you give an example of how you would envision doing this?